# How do I delete a Lucene index without affecting other non-index files in the directory?

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

I am wanting to write back an in-memory Lucene index to disk, overtop of the originally-loaded index. Currently if I call `Directory.Copy( _ramDirectory, _fileSystemDirectory, false )`, it simply adds the new files to the directory but leaves the old (stale) ones there.

I tried calling:

```
new IndexWriter( _fsd, _analyzer, true, IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED ).Close();
```

...(to create a new empty index in the directory) but this has strange behavior and sometimes results in the entire index being wiped clean on the next run of the program.

Is there any way I can simply get a list of the files a file system index is currently using so I can delete them manually? I don't want to blindly erase all files in the directory in case there are some non-index files there.

Apparently `FSDirectory.ListAll()` lists all files in the physical directory, whether or not they are actually part of the index. Is there any way I can tell if a particular file is used/created by the index? I mean I can't even check file extensions due to Lucene's bizarre file naming conventions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd definitely recommend that you dont mix other files in a Lucene index folder.

The best solution would be to create a new index using the IndexWriter constructor that has the create parameter, which will create a new index at the location. Then you use the `IndexWriter.AddIndexesNoOptimize(Directory[] dirs)` method to add your RamDirectory to the FSDirectory

Comment: Even if you use CFS, I think you'll still have segments.gen, segments* and *.del (at least).

Comment: I totally agree, but in my application the user can customize the location of the index, thus they could (accidentally) set it to some existing important folder--I really don't want an update to the index to completely wipe that folder clean.

Comment: Marked as answer because it is actually the best answer to the question as stated, though Xodarap's point may actually make the question irrelevant (in my case at least).

Answer (score 3):

1. If you're using Lucene 2.9 or greater, all IndexWriters use a behind-the-scenes RAM directory, which will probably be faster than you making your own RAM directory and then attempting to manually flush to disk. See the [FAQ about NRT](http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/NearRealtimeSearch).
2. If you really want to use your own RAM directory, open the existing (non-RAM) index and then do `IndexWriter.DeleteAll()` and optimize.

Comment: Hmm, interesting! Didn't realize that. That might actually make things  a lot easier--I was planning to check the size of the index and use a file system directory if the index was above a certain size--does this "behind the scenes" IndexWriter do that for me?

Comment: @chaiguy: You can see `IndexWriter.SetMaxBufferedDocs` and `IndexWriter.SetRAMBufferSizeMB`.